# React implement highlight on letter based search in list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown

```
Code:
const fruit = [watermelon, apple, orange, lime];
const listItems = fruit .map((number) =>  <li>{number}</li>)
```

i am implementing a simple list like a drop down.
when i press "a" character "apple" to be highlighted.
i do want do want use "SELECT" tag since it has issue in IE.
any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: you can do it by onChange event where just filter out results and set a property of background.

Comment: @Pankaj could please share example if possible